# Filter username from tweet

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following string:

```
No, @Username, I did not go to the supermarket yet
```

I use the following regex to label all usernames:

```
$tweet = preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '{USER:$1}', $tweet);
```

resulting into:

```
No, {USER:UserName}, I did not go to the supermarket yet
```

However, I have a table with twitter users, and would like to lookup the user_id so that I can  instead output:

```
No, {USER:4324322}, I did not go to the supermarket yet
```

or, if no matching username has been found, the default output as it is now:

```
No, {USER:UserName}, I did not go to the supermarket yet
```

For this, I first need to only preg_match all @usernames, look them up, and then insert the proper {label} back into the tweet. I'm somewhat confused on how to structure this. Who can help? Consider the code to check for the username in the database something like this:

```
$user = db_result(db_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", $match));
if ($user = true) { // match found
  $label = '{USER:'. $user .'}';
}
else {
  $label = '{USER:'. $match .'}';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a shorter way of matching Twitter usernames than "`/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i`". It is "`/@(\w+)/`". See this: http://ideone.com/b7N1k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_callback`](http://php.net/preg_match_callback).

Example:

```
$tweet = preg_match_callback("(@([a-z0-9_]+))i",function($m) {
    static $cache = Array();
    $user = $m[1];
    if( !isset($cache[$user]))
        list($cache[$user]) = db_result(db_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '%s'",$user));
    return "{USER:".($cache[$user] ? $cache[$user] : $user)."}";
},$tweet);
```